# Unable to write data in second sheet of excel using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to write data into second sheet of excel using Apache POI in selenium web driver. It showing up a Null point exception error. However, i am able to write data in first sheet. Below is my code,

```
package RWExcel;

import java.io.File;   
import java.io.FileInputStream;   
import java.io.FileOutputStream;    

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;    
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;    

public class WriteExcel {    

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

File src = new File("D:/selenium/Test/ReadExcel.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet0 = wbook.getSheetAt(1);

sheet0.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");

sheet0.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue("Fail");

FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(src);
wbook.write(output);
wbook.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: when you are getting Null pointer exception?

Comment: Exception occurs across this line sheet0.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");                           when i trying to write value in the cell 0,2 by keeping the cells 0,0 and 0,1 as blank cell